# How to detect the number of distinct words in a string with Regex?

Tags: regex, regexp-like

I would like to detect if a string contains multiple different words and would like to limit the number of words. Words all kinds of characters, except spaces.

E.g.: I want to check if the following strings have no more than three distinct words:

```
lorum                               -> True
lorum ipsum                         -> True
lorum ipsum dolor                   -> True
lorem lorem ipsum dolor ipsum ipsum -> True
lorem lorem <=>                     -> True
1 2 3                               -> True

lorem ipsum dolor sit lorum         -> False
lorem ipsum dolor sit               -> False
1 2 3 4                             -> False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my great surprise this is actually achievable with regular expression.
This is really ugly and inefficient, but it works.

You should probably not use it though: this is not the right tool for this job.

```
/^(\S*)(?: \1)*(?:(?: (\S*))(?: \1| \2)*(?: (\S*))?)?(?: \1| \2| \3)*$/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/0cgoFF/1